# Dynamic SQL Query With Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query and it's creating a PIVOT table.

Here is it.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
   Name
  ,Year
  ,sum(Payment) as TotalPayment  
  FROM Orders
  group by Name,Date
 ) as Tablo
 PIVOT
 (
    SUM(TotalPayment)
    FOR Date IN ([2009-11],[2009-12],[2010-01])
 )
 AS p
```

It's getting monthly total payment and the guy who wrote this query adding year-month manually every month. I need to do it dynamically.

How can I get month-year dynamically from table using SQL query with loop or something like that ?

Thanks for your helps !

Comment: use `Dynamic SQL`

Comment: Use something along the lines of `DATEADD(MONTH,-2,GETDATE())`

Comment: @Squirrel how :think:

Comment: What about to use 'relative' month instead to absolute one. Then, you can take all times the last 12 months, for example: `group by Name, datediff(month,Date,getdate() as r_month ) ` ... `FOR r_month IN ([-1], [-2], ... )` Remember to limit the number of months on `where` clause.

Comment: search this site for Dynamic PIVOT SQL Server

Comment: @danihp thansk for your answer, but you explain it spesifically by an example query ?

Comment: @ÖmürCanYurdugül, I can do it if this is a solution for you.

Comment: @danihp It can work for me i think.

Comment: @ÖmürCanYurdugül, ok, I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sugges to you about to use `relative` time and not `absolute` one. In this way, your query is all time up to date. Here I post a sample on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6f988b/7)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t ( d date, i int );
insert into t values
( '2016-01-01', 100 ),
-- ... some other data
( '2017-12-13', 100 );
```

I write the query step by step using CTE:

```
with 
cooked as          --change to relative months (from today)
( select datediff(MONTH,getdate(), d ) as dif, i
  from t
),
filtered as        --just take the last 12 months
( select dif as Date, i as TotalPayment
  from cooked
  where dif > -12
)
select *           --pivoting
from filtered
PIVOT
 (
    SUM(TotalPayment)
    FOR Date IN ([-11],[-10],[-9],[-8],
                 [-7],[-6],[-5],[-4],
                 [-3],[-2],[-1],[0])
 )
 AS p
```

Here the **[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6f988b/7/0)**, where `[0]` means this moth and `[-11]` means 12 moths ago:

```
| -11 | -10 |  -9 |  -8 |  -7 |  -6 |  -5 |  -4 |  -3 |  -2 |  -1 |   0 |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
| 500 | 500 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 |
```